# msgpack: messaging between C++ and java

Tags: java, c++, msgpack

I have two applications (one written in C++ and other in Java). I use `msgpack` to pack the C++ class to the binary format. Then I send this to the Java side. I wonder if I unpack this message in java (using `msgpack` too) do I get the correct Java class object?

Consider the following example:

```
// C++
class Foo
{
public:
    // some methods here...
    void Pack(uint8_t *data, size_t size);
private:
    std::string m1_;
    std::string m2_;
    int m3_;
public:
    MSGPACK_DEFINE(m1_, m2_, m3_);
}

void Foo::Pack(uint8_t *data, size_t size)
{
    msgpack::sbuffer sbuf;
    msgpack::pack(sbuf, *this);

    data = sbuf.data();
    size = sbuf.size();
}
```

And Java side:

```
// Java

public class Foo
{

    public void Unpack(byte[] raw, Foo obj)
    {
        MessagePack msgpack = new MessagePack();
        try
        {
            obj = msgpack.read(raw, Foo.class);
            // Does obj's m1_, m2_ and m3_ contains proper values from C++ class Foo?
        }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }

    // ...

    private String m1_;
    private String m2_;
    private int m3_;
}
```

I don't want to pack the Foo's members one by one because I have a lot of them.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As it is said on msgpack website

> MessagePack is an efficient binary serialization format. It lets you exchange data among multiple languages like JSON.

So the answer is "yes, your java object should be properly deserialized"

Comment: @PetterFriberg I guess you're right, I got wrong with this one, should have been paying closer attention

Comment: @VasilyAlexeev no problem, continue to review if you have doubts you can always pass by the [SOCVR room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers)